# Is it possible to develop an Outlook Add-In that will handle multiple emails?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

I am attempting to create an Outlook add-in that will allow me to select multiple emails (hopefully by highlighting them) and will then have a button that will allow me to perform an action on each of the highlighted emails. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I haven't been able to find any documentation for this scenario. At the moment, I am making use of the MessageReadCommandSurface extension within my XML file - however this appears to only work if one email is selected and is greyed out when more than one is highlighted.

A potential solution is to build my own custom popup that can allow me to select multiple emails but that seems more time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web add-ins work in the context of a single item.

If you want to deal with multiple items in Outlook you need to develop a COM add-in. Note, in this case, your add-in will be working on the desktop edition of Outlook.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response and answer. That is a little disappointing you can't operate on more than one item using the web browser version. I'll take a look at creating something custom then! Thanks again.